# How do I setup my env to use google maps with asp.net w/ react/redux project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

New asp.net dev here. I am trying to import google maps API into my project for use. My steps so far are as follows:

- Created google account with key, places API, and Map Embed API enabled
- Create base asp.net w/ react & redux project
- run two npm commands: `npm i google-map-react`, and `npm i "@types/google-map-react"`
- Create a basic typescript page with following code:

  ```
   import * as React from 'react';
    import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
    import * as GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';


    export class MapTest2 extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        public render() {
            return <div>
                map here
                </div>;
        }
    }
  ```

However when I try to actually run the project, I get a large number of errors:

[image: error list]

If I remove the google import statement the solution will run with no issues.

I have tried installing different google map apis (e.g. `'@react-google-maps/api', 'googlemaps' etc.)` and different import statements (e.g. `import { GoogleMap } from '@react-google-maps/api';` but all of them end up with this same issue of errors on the screen. Can anyone help with setting up my env to be able to use google maps api?

Comment: What version of TS you're using?
It seems it's about incompatibility with the TS version

Comment: @AliTitan my TS is on version: 2.4.1 according to package.json file